# Cannot download Wicket-1.4 in Netbeans-7

Tags: netbeans, wicket, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins, wicket-1.4

I go to http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3586/wicket-1-4-support and just downloaded the plugin and tried to install it but I am getting this error:

> Some plugins require plugin Editor
>   Library to be installed. The plugin
>   Editor Library is requested in version
>   >= 1.37.0.8.2 (release version 1)
>   but only 3.8.1.13.8 (of release
>   version different from 1) was found.
>   The following plugin is affected:
>   Wicket Support

how to solve it?

Comment: Not sure when you last looked at the Wicket plugin, but it seems that Geertjan Wielanga has been doing some work on it recently. http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/visual_wicket_parsing http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/modular_wicket_versioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you check in last few hours on plugin support page you listed, but there seems to be some updates in regards of this problem. Some users reported problem was solved. However it seems that plugin (version 4.10) is behind with current available version of Wicket (4.17)